# To remove duplication of data if within 7 days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Following is my table and sample data

```
DECLARE @Employee_Log table(ID int,eid int, ecode varchar(100), emp_startdate date)



  INSERT INTO @Employee_Log
SELECT 1, 1, 'aaa','2019-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'aaa','2019-01-05'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'bbb','2019-01-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'aaa','2019-01-03'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, 'aaa','2019-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1, 'aaa','2019-02-15'
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 1, 'aaa','2019-02-19'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 1, 'aaa','2019-02-28'
```

In the above data I want to remove the duplication based on `eid` and `ecode` .If the `emp_startdate` are within 7 days then take the latest data and ignore the rest data.

I tried the following code but how to add the condition check for week range

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eid,ecode ORDER BY emp_startdate desc) as rownum,
ID,eid,ecode,emp_startdate
FROM @Employee_Log
```

I want the result as shown below

```
  ID    eid ecode   emp_startdate
    2   1   aaa      2019-01-05
    5   1   aaa      2019-02-01
    4   2   aaa      2019-01-03
    7   1   aaa      2019-02-19
    8   1   aaa      2019-02-28
    3   1   bbb      2019-01-03
```

Comment: What happens if there be three "duplicate" records, such that the first is within a week of the second, and the second be within a week of the first.  What gets deleted in this case?

Comment: "if the emp_startdate are within a week range" Are you talking about a calendar week or simply no more than 7 days apart? if it's the first, what day does your week start?

Comment: emp_startdate for a particular eid should be 7 days apart added few more sample data...hope it clear now

Comment: Again the same problem with your question, when you say "remove the duplication based on eid and ecode", how did you managed to eliminate `3, 1, 'bbb','2019-01-03'` the ecode is `bbb` here.

Comment: edited the output..thanks

Comment: Also what do you consider to be the week start day? and also how did you manage to eliminate `2019-02-15`? `2019-02-15` and `2019-02-19` are in two different weeks.

Comment: emp_startdate for a particular eid should be 7 days apart as the difference between 2019-02-15 and 2019-02-19  is 4 ignoring the 15th data

Comment: I had posted this in MSDN got few answers there...so just posting the link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e10f2139-a1c8-4b2d-ab91-43feba22c4a7/to-remove-duplication-of-data-if-within-7-days?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure what you want to happen if more than 2 events happen in the same 7 days. But this solution will get the latest date of all series of dates where the difference between dates is 7 days or less.

```
select ID,eid,ecode,emp_startdate
from
(
select ID,
eid,
ecode,
emp_startdate,
datediff(day
    ,emp_startdate
    ,lead(emp_startdate) 
        over
        (partition by eid,ecode order by emp_startdate)) l 
from  @Employee_Log
) a
where l is null or l>7

ID     eid     ecode     emp_startdate
--     ---     -----     -------------
3       1       bbb       2019-01-03
2       1       aaa       2019-01-05
5       1       aaa       2019-02-01
7       1       aaa       2019-02-19
8       1       aaa       2019-02-28
4       2       aaa       2019-01-03
```

Comment: Thanks soren for the help

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you what you have asked to get in plain English in your question but your sample data and desired output contradicts your own question:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eid , ecode , YEAR(emp_startdate) 
                                       , DATEPART(WEEK, emp_startdate)
                           ORDER BY emp_startdate DESC
                          ) AS rownum
      , ID
      , eid
      , ecode
      , emp_startdate
    FROM @Employee_Log
) x
WHERE x.rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Output not matched with Expected output.

Comment: @SurajKumar yes I know, but it matches based on what is asked in the question in plain english.  It appears to me that the desired output in the question contradicts the question itself.